# Cannot use react-input-mask with a children component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to mask a Material UI TextField, and reading some solutions on internet I got this code:

```
       <InputMask
          mask="(0)999 999 99 99"
          value={phone}
          disabled={false}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          {(inputProps: Props & TextFieldProps) => (
            <TextField
              {...inputProps}
              type="tel"
              label={t("addDriverModal.phone")}
            />
          )}
        </InputMask>
```

But it gets me this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Props | Readonly<Props>): ReactInputMask', gave the following error.
    Type '(inputProps: Props & TextFieldProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Props, context: any): ReactInputMask', gave the following error.
    Type '(inputProps: Props & TextFieldProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2769)
```

So I cannot pass a TextField as a children for InputMask component.

I also tried this solution:

```
        <InputMask
          mask="(0)999 999 99 99"
          value={phone}
          disabled={false}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <TextField
            id="outlined-basic"
            label="Teléfono"
            variant="outlined"
            style={{
              border: "2px solid #fff",
              borderRadius: "4px",
              color: "white",
            }}
            InputLabelProps={{ style: { color: "white" } }}
            sx={{ input: { color: "white" } }}
          />
        </InputMask>
```

But when I start the app, in console displays this error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: react-input-mask: children must be a function
```

So really I cannot use any solution for masking my MUI TextField.
I'm using this versions:

```
   "react": "^18.1.0",
   "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
   "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
   "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
   "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
   "@types/react-input-mask": "^3.0.1",
```

And I'm using Typescript, and functional components.

Answer (score 12):

The type definitions package you are using does not correspond to the version of the package. You should either:

- Downgrade `@types/react-input-mask` to `2.0.4` to match the package
- Or upgrade `react-input-mask` to version `3.0.0-alpha.2` to match the typing.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and upgrading `react-input-mask` to version `3.0.0-alpha.2` resolve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

For v16 of `react`, below config of `react-input-mask` works fine.

```
"@types/react-input-mask": "2.0.4",
"react-input-mask": "^2.0.4"
```

After upgrading react to v18, you need to also upgrade the versions for `react-input-mask` and that should fix this error.

```
"@types/react-input-mask": "3.0.2",
"react-input-mask": "3.0.0-alpha.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

@PetePearl offered a solution over on [the GitHub issue queue](https://github.com/sanniassin/react-input-mask/issues/139#issuecomment-1307161406) that uses `Omit` to replace the typing for `children`:

```js
import InputMask, { Props as InputMaskProps } from 'react-input-mask';

type TInputMaskCorrect = Omit<InputMaskProps, 'children'> & { children?: (inputProps: any) => JSX.Element };
const InputMaskCorrect: React.FC<TInputMaskCorrect> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const child = children as ReactNode;
  return (
    <InputMask {...props}>
      {children}
    </InputMask>
  );
}
```

Then use `<InputMaskCorrect>` in place of `<InputMask>`.

Alternatively, you can also upgrade to `react-input-mask@3.0.0-alpha.2`, but the package hasn't been updated in the last 3 years. YMMV, details in the issue queue comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, it worked for me to update `react-input-mask` to version `3.0.0-alpha.2`.

Its my code finally:

```
<FormControl fullWidth={false} sx={{ width: '290px', mb: 6 }}>
        <Controller
          name='cnpj'
          control={control}
          render={(props) => (
            <InputMask
              mask="99.999.999/9999-99"
              value={props.field.value}
              disabled={false}
              onChange={(value): void => {
                props.field.onChange(value)
                changeHandler(value)
              }}
            >
              <TextField
                disabled={false}
                name="cnpj"
                type="text"
                label='Cnpj'
                placeholder='(e.g.: 60.133.365/0001-16)'
                error={Boolean(errors.cnpj)} 
              />
            </InputMask>
          )}
        />
        {errors.cnpj && <FormHelperText sx={{ color: 'error.main' }}>{errors.cnpj.message}</FormHelperText>}
      </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

add @ts-ignore in example on gitHub same problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-u5u2rb?file=TextFieldMask.tsx

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Carefully check what you are passing in as the child, I was getting this error and it turned out I was simply referencing properties on Formik that didn't exist.